# How to parallelize or use multi-cores to speed up a while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a instance with 16-core processor and I have a while loop like below,

```
count = 200000
num = 0

pbar = tqdm(total=count)
lst = []
while num <= count:
    random_folder = os.path.join(path, np.random.choice(os.listdir(path)))
    file_path = os.path.join(path, np.random.choice(os.listdir(random_folder)))
    if not os.path.isdir(file_path):
        lst.append(file_path)
        pbar.update(1)
        num += 1
```

When I tried to run this code on a server, the estimated time is really long

```
 0%|          | 138/200000 [02:14<51:25:11,  1.08it/s]
```

I have tried to use numpy to get random choice but it's still slow. Is there any way I can take advantage of my multi-core cpu and speed up this while loop? It's just collecting random files from sub folders. Really appreciate any help. Thanks

Update:

```
path = "/home/user12/pdf_files"

def get_random_file(num_of_files):
    count = 0
    random_files = []
    while count <  num_of_files:
        random_folder = os.path.join(path, random.choice(os.listdir(path)))
        file_path = os.path.join(path, random.choice(os.listdir(random_folder)))
        if not os.path.isdir(file_path):
            resumes_list.append(file_path)
            count += 1
    return random_files

with Pool(16) as p:
    random_files = p.map(get_random_file, (1000/16,))
```

Comment: What is your code doing?

Comment: @BalajiAmbresh So, `path` variable is a folder name which has multiple sub-folders in it. So I'm picking random folder from those sub-folders and storing it in variable called `random_folder`. After getting a random folder then I'm getting a list of all the files in that random folder (`mostly .pdf files`) and picking a random file from it and storing it in `file_path` variable. I'm doing that till count reaches 200000

Comment: I'm guessing you want to pick `count` number of `pdf` files. Be sure to account for duplicates. For example, 2 iterations of the loop could pick the same `pdf` file under the same folder.

Comment: @BalajiAmbresh Yeah. Sure I totally forgot about it as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use multi processing and use all cores at the same time.

See https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html

Something like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def get_random_file(num_of_files):
    # your logic goes here
    count = 0
    random_files = []
    while count <  num_of_files: 
        count += 1
        pass
        #get random file and append to 'random_files'
    return random_files

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(16) as p:
        num_of_files = [200000/16 for i in range(1,16)]
        random_files = p.map(get_random_file,num_of_files)
        # random_files is a list of lists - you need to merge them into one list
```

Comment: what should be the input to the function `get_random_file` in my case? How can I write my while condition here. Also, how can I stop it when it reaches the count value `200000`

Comment: Code was updated. Each copy of the function will create  200000/16 random files. This will run in parallel

Comment: Thank you so much.. Let me check it.

Comment: Is there a way to include `tqdm` into this to check the status of 16 parallel jobs?

Comment: @user_12 I am not sure about tqdm.. Start by making it work without tqdm.

Comment: So I've tried to use it but it's only returning a single inner list with 63 files in it. I tried it with `1000/16`.

Comment: If you face issues - share the code. (Code was modified - have a look and retry)

Comment: I have shared the code. Sure let me try the updated code.

Comment: You are almost there - see the latest code I have posted